# Sidekiq not processing more than one queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have successfully configured Sidekiq for my use but now it is not processing more than one queue. It is only processing the queue that is written first in configuration file. For instance:

```
---
:verbose: true

:concurrency: 100
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:queues :
  - [kritikal , 5]
  - [critical , 4]
```

In this case it is only processing  kritikal queue. And in following case:

```
---
:verbose: true

:concurrency: 100
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid  
staging:
  :concurrency: 10
production:
  :concurrency: 20
:queues :
  - [critical , 4]
  - [kritikal , 5]
```

It is only processing critical queue. Could anyone tell me where I could be going wrong?

Comment: How are you running sidekiq (command line, daemon)? What region are you running in? Dev? Staging?

Comment: i m using dev mode in command line using bundle exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know whether that was the problem but I synced my client and server redis configuration, removed space again from `:queue :` and restarted my system and  Voila!! it is working now. Though I personally do not believe that syncing redis server was a problem because one queue was getting executed in any case.

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { :url => 'redis://localhost:6379' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { :size => 1 }
    config.redis = { :url => 'redis://localhost:6379' }
end
```

Comment: Can you post your updated config in the answer so it can help others?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because you have extra white space in the `:queues :` declaration.

Comment: At first I did not have that space but it was the same issue then too. So I deliberately added one to try if that might be the problem but still no use.

Comment: Mike, is the YAML parser in Sidekiq very strict and filtering out objects in the config?

Comment: Sidekiq uses the standard Ruby YAML parser.  Typically you will get an error, it wouldn't just silently drop things.